# Find duplicate images in directory on OSX?

Tags: macos

I'm working in OSX and I have a directory of 548 images. I'd like to identify duplicates. Is there a way I can do this from the command line?

I found a recommendation on a Linux forum to use something like this, and then sort and look for non-uniques:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';'
```

But on OSX this produces `find: md5sum: No such file or directory`.

Comment: On macos, it's `sum`

Comment: `sum` does a basic checksum; I'd use `md5 -r` instead.